# ModX Ditto: Orderby TVs?

Tags: content-management-system, modx, modx-evolution, ditto

I want to order Dittos results by a TV called 'city'

I have set out my Ditto call as such:

```
[!Ditto? &parents=`87` &display=`99` &orderBy=`city ASC` &tpl=`dittotpl`!]
```

But this doesnt work.

I cannot find any resources to do this online. Can any help me out? Thanks

Comment: your orderBy attrib is correct, are you getting any output at all? errors? [you are using Evo or Revo? - remove the last ! for Revo]

Comment: @SeanKimball I am using Evo, I am getting output but its not sorting (ie the order doesnt change if I change the tv, remove it, make it DESC, etc). No errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had inserted the `&orderBy=` statement after I created the initial Ditto statement. TinyMCE wrapped this in a `<span>` for some reason. Removed that and all is fine